# In my laravel blog website, i want to display post author as the logged in admin and display in the post view

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I've been having issues displaying author of a post. I created a one to many relationship between admin and post. But in my view (post.blade.php) one admin is showing in all posts as an author rather than the respective admins who created the post. It only assigns the newest admin as the author to all other posts made by different admins, how do i get rid of this error please?.[When i die and dumb post, it shows the admin_id perfectly.

PostController for post that is shown in the front end, controller handling what visitors sees when they visit the page:

```php
class PostController extends Controller
{
    public function post(Request $request, post $post//provided from the post model, category $category)
    {
        $posts = post::all();
        $postss = post::where('status', 1)->orderBy('created_at', 'asc')->limit(1)->get();
        $categories = $category::all();

        //dd ($post);
        return view('user/layout/post', compact('post', 'posts','categories', 'postss'));
    }
    }
```

PostController for admin side:

```php
class PostController extends Controller
{
      /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth:admin');
    }
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $posts = post::all(); //displays all posts in the admin section
        return view('admin.post.list', compact('posts'));
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {

        if (Auth::user()->can('posts.create')) {
      //this function is to permit admin to create posts
            $categories = category::all();
            return view('admin.post.post', compact('categories'));
        }
        return redirect(route('admin.home'));
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request) //validates and stores the posts
    {
        $this -> validate($request, [
            'title' => 'required',
            'subtitle' => 'required',
            'slug' => 'required',
            'body' => 'required',
            'image' => 'required',
        ]);
        if($request->hasFile('image')){
            $image = $request->file('image');
            $filename = time() . '.' . $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $location = public_path('images/' . $image);
            Image::make($image)->save($location);
            return response()->json(['uploaded' => '/images/'.$image]);
        }
        $post = new post;
        $post -> title = $request -> title;
        $post -> subtitle = $request -> subtitle;
        $post -> body = $request -> body;
        $post -> slug = $request -> slug;
        $post -> image = $filename;
        $post -> status = $request -> status;
        $post->admin_id = Auth::user()->id;

        $post -> save();
        $post -> categories() -> sync($request -> categories );

        return redirect(route('post.index'));
    }
}
```

This is my post model

```php
<?php

    namespace App\Model\user;

    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
    use App\Model\admin\admin;
    use CyrildeWit\EloquentViewable\Viewable;

    class post extends Model
    {
        use Viewable;
        public function categories()
        {
            return $this->belongsToMany('App\Model\user\category', 'category_posts')->withTimeStamps();
        }

        public function admin()
        {
            return $this->belongsTo(admin::class);
        }

        public function getRouteKeyName()
        {
            return 'slug';
        }
    }
```

This is my post.blade.php:

```php
    <div class="col-md-7">
        <article class="post-single">
          <div class="post-body">
            <strong> created at {{ date('F d, Y',  strtotime($post->created_at)) }}</strong>
            @foreach($post->categories as $category)
            <strong class="pull-right" style="margin-right:20px">
              <a href="{{ route('category', $category->slug)}}">{{$category -> name}} </a>
          </strong>
          <br>
          @endforeach
          {!!htmlspecialchars_decode($post->body)!!}
      </div>

  </article>
         <div class="writter-section">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-7 col-lg-offset-1">
                        <div id="writter">
                            <ul class="writter-list">
                                <li>
                                    <div class="wriiter">
                                        <div class="writter-pic">
                                            <img src="{{ asset('author_images/'. $post->admin->Adminimage)}}">
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="writter-text">
                                            <h4 class="upper"> {{ $post->admin->id}} </h4>
                                            <h5> {{ $post->admin->description}}</h5>
                                            <p>  </p>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

This is the posts database:

```php
 public function up()
        {
            Schema::create('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
                $table->increments('id');
                $table->integer('admin_id')->unsigned();
                $table->string('title',255);
                $table->string('subtitle',100);
                $table->string('slug',100);
                $table->text('body');
                $table->boolean('status')->nullable();
                $table->string('image');
                $table->timestamps(); 

                $table->foreign('admin_id')
                      ->references('id')->on('admins')
                      ->onDelete('cascade');

        }

        /**
         * Reverse the migrations.
         *
         * @return void
         */
        public function down()
        {
            Schema::dropIfExists('posts');
        }
    }
```

This is the admins database

```php
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('admins', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->string('Adminimage');
            $table->string('password');
            $table->string('description');
            $table->string('phone');
            $table->boolean('status');
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->string('description');
            $table->rememberToken();
        });
    }
```

In the postblade view new authors overwrites the previous original authors. So If i have 6 posts, all 6 posts have an author instead of it's original author. For better understanding you can check this link(the link to the website with the error) blog.dodo.ng, thank you all

Comment: I'm struggling to understand the problem. Is there an issue with showing the post or creating it (or both)?

Comment: I was having an issue showing each post author,  it only shows one author for all posts,  instead of each post with its own authors! @JonasStaudenmeir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured what was wrong with my blog post,  I was passing a wrong value of post in my post.blade.php file.  I was using the value of $postss in my Post controller for user rather than the value of $post from post $post in the post function (first function in my post controller for user). Thank you all